# batch download files from website in repeating pattern

Tags: download

I want to download a bunch of files from a website. They are named in the following manner:

xyz.com/yyyy/mm/yyyymmdd.jpge

for example,
xyz.com/2015/11/20151115.jpg

can I automate this?

Comment: Yes you can automate it. You have not specified under what kind of interface you would like to automate it with. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: And what OS you're on. There are some cross-platform tools (JDownload and curl come to mind), but there may be additional options if we know what OS you want to do this on.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'd like to point out that the question does not ask for a script, only a method of accomplishing the task.

Answer (score 0):

If they are all linked to on the site (even by means of an index) , you can use a webcrawler like [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) to download everything. You just have to configure it properly (proper includes, excludes, and speed).